# how to verify root CA bundle via openssl commands?

Tags: php

i added a self-signed certificate to root CA bundle,so i need to validate the whole file "ca-bundle.crt".
is there any openssl command to do this?
if there is, i can use code system("openssl xxxx") to do this.
i had tried the command "openssl verify ..path/ca-bundle.crt", it can't validate self-signed certificate.

Comment: my ca-bundle.crt include over 150 certificates.

Comment: ok, i had resolved it today, the command as "openssl verify -CAfile ~/ca-bundle.crt ~/current.crt". this command can do validate.

Comment: would be interesting to know how to do the same with openssl_verify.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the [online SSL checker](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker) to see how your certificate is doing.

Comment: thx for your answer, but i don't want to validate via internet.